# Use microsoft.applicationinsights.tracelistener for ASP.Net Core 3.1 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have installed Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore in my ASP.Net Core 3.1 web application and did setup using next code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("aiInstrumentationKey");
}
```

After tracing some output string into `Trace.Information("Test trace string")` found it outputs to console, but not into application insights traces. Found that it possible for microsoft.applicationinsights.tracelistener to fix this issue, but haven't found resources that explicitly saying how to configure this.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is fairy simple: just add `Trace.Listeners.Add(new ApplicationInsightsTraceListener("aiInstrumentationKey"));` after application insights telemtry setup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry("aiInstrumentationKey");
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new ApplicationInsightsTraceListener("aiInstrumentationKey"));
}
```